# Is there any regex to find that a value is hashmap or not?

Tags: regex, hash, cryptography, language-agnostic

Is there any regex to find that a value is hashmap or not?

I want to build an PL/SQL function to say that a value is hashed or not?

For e.g
1. TIM  2. F6099C0932D0E2B13286218F99C265975B33FD84

My Regex should have intelligence to tell me that expression 1 (Tim) is not hashmaped.
Whereas expression 2 (F6099C0932D0E2B13286218F99C265975B33FD84) is hashmaped.

Comment: Who says F6099C0932D0E2B13286218F99C265975B33FD84 can't be a name like Tim? F6099C0932D0E2B13286218F99C265975B33FD84 will be the name of Elon Musk's next child.

Comment: See [falsehoods programmers believe about names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/). `null` is a name. Anything is a name. A regex can be `/^[A-F\d]{40}$/` and you can assume that no numbers are in names, but this guarantees nothing. You could look names up in a dictionary but that still fails--it's possible that the hash winds up colliding with a name in the dictionary, and it's possible that the dict doesn't contain someone's name.

Answer (score 1):

A hash is just a number of bits of a particular size. Cryptographic hashes generally have a 256 to 512 bit output size to achieve a security of about 128-256 bits to achieve collision resistance.

Other hashes used in a hash map may be smaller, as collision resistance is usually not required; instead the hash just needs to be well distributed, so that hashed values are distributed equally.

Computers generally only address bytes, not bits. So commonly the hashes are a multiple of 8 bits. Even more generally, they are commonly a power of two, or two or three powers of two added together (160 bits for 128 + 32 bits).

Now to view those well distributed bytes we need to have some kind of way to view these bit values using printable characters. One way to do that is base 64. However, for these relatively short values hexadecimals are usually preferred, and that's what you have in the question.

So can you see if it is a hash value or not? Well, yes and no. You can see with a pretty good likelihood that it is a 40 character hexadecimal value, which *represents* a 20 bytes or 20 * 8 = 160 bit value. We can also "see" that it is pretty well distributed and that it doesn't encode printable ASCII (as there are values above 7E hex).

Testing with a regex that the contents are (upper or lowercase) hexadecimals is easy  enough. That it is 40 characters for 160 bits should be easy as well. However, to test that it is indeed a well distributed value is not really possible with regular expressions. It is even not easy for any program code, as "random" values may now and then look surprisingly non-random. Besides that, not only hashes consist of well distributed byte values. Ciphertext and - of course - random byte values have similar properties.

So, yeah, you can verify that the output format is compatible with a hash value, but testing if it **is** a hash value is not really possible.

---

The regexp:

```
[0-9A-Fa-f]{40}
```

would of course wipe "Tim" out. You can be 100% sure that "Tim" is not a 160 bit hash value encoded in hexadecimals after all.